# Is there a way to compute Enumerables using a String Expression in C#

Tags: c#, string, expression, ienumerable

I have been looking for any tip or idea about to Compute Enumerables using a String Expression, I mean by compute to execute operations like Min, Max, Average and Sum.

I am looking for something like This..

```
    // PARAMETER MODEL
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price1 { get; set; }
        public double Price2 { get; set; }
        public double Price3 { get; set; }
        public double Price4 { get; set; }
    }

    // GETS AN ENUMERABLE COLLECTION OF PARAMETERS
    IEnumerable<Parameter> currentParameters = ParameterCreator.GetParameters();

    // HERE IS MY QUESTION
    double maxPrice = currentParameters.Compute("MAX[Price2]");
```

Where **Price2** String Expressions indicates a property in Parameter Class.
**MAX** a Compute through Price2 parameter on the Enumerable Collection.
And **Compute**, a dummy extension method on any package or framework.

Does anyone has any idea whether there is any package, framework or anything to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll need to write a parser for your simple language and a visitor to interpret it. You can use something like Sprache for this. However, this smells a lot like an XY problem. Depending on your use case (is the instruction coming from a user, perhaps over the wire? do all "operations" involve reducing a list to a single element?), this can be solved in a number of simpler ways, such as passing delegates or lambda expressions, or a simple switch over an enum.

Comment: You could dust off the old [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) library.

Comment: `List<T>` has a max method: `var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };var max = list.Max(x => x);`. Wouldn't that do?